# "Please, do your best for the purpose that I remember it."

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I want to ask my tutor to help me with memorizing a complex issue that has many many details, and to do his best for it.

I wrote the sentence the following sentence for him, but something in it (in the last part) doesn't look to me as being natural.

> "Please, do your best for the purpose that I remember it."

Comment: _For the purpose_ isn't appropriate here. 'Please do your best to help me [to] remember it.'

Comment: You are asking a tutor to do their best to help you memorize something complex? Is this a typical request for tutors? Maybe, you should be asking for them to explain it  in such a way that you find it easier to understand. There's a famous line from a movie that goes something like: "Explain it me as if I were a five year old”